# Current through a capacitor in AC Circuits

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, inductance

I'm a little confused on the equation for the instantaneous current through a capacitor in AC circuits.

My textbook has it as:

$$i_C = \omega CV \ cos(\omega t + \pi/2) = -\omega CV \ sin(\omega t)$$

where $\omega$ = angular frequency, $C$ is the capacitance, and $V$ is the voltage across the capacitor.

I'm also seeing it in some places online (and in the problem "hints" for my homework) without the the "+ $\pi/2$" part, and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

To add to my confusion, the equation for the current through the inductor in the problem "hints", is consistent with the textbook:

$$i_L = (V/\omega L) \ cos(\omega t - \pi/2) = (V/\omega L) \ sin(\omega t)$$

The problem in question relates to this circuit:
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your confusion? Are you wondering about the phases? Also, do you know calculus and have familiarity with complex numbers?

Comment: $cos(\omega t-\pi/2)=sin(\omega t), cos(\omega t+\pi/2)=-sin(\omega t)$ so it just says the one current is opposed to the other.

Comment: To clarify my confusion, my homework problem is saying i_c =  wCVcos(wt), not wCVcos(wt+pi/2), and I don't know why. My understanding is that the current should lead the voltage, so the it should include the +pi/2 term. And I am familiar with calculus and complex numbers

Comment: It depends on the initial conditions. If you write one as sin and the other as cos with the same angular frequency, that means they are 90 degrees out of phase. If you write two functions as cos or sin but one is negative and the other positive that makes them 180 degrees out of phase. Any combination of these and an explicitly written phase difference can convey the right relationship. The point of the initial conditions and the functional for is that you choose to use cos (with no explicit phase), for example, for a function that will be maximum at t=0, and sin for one which will be minimum.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was missing. The initial conditions can be a sine or cosine function. I think my textbook is using cosine as the default, but the homework problem used sine. I didn't realize it could be either of them, depending on the configuration of the voltage source.

Answer (score 0):

The pi/2 term comes about when converting angular measure from degree units to radian units, where 2(pi) radians equals 360 degrees.

BTW here is a simple way to visualize current flow through a capacitor:

Imagine two flat metal plates facing each other with nothing but air between them. Each plate is connected to a wire into which we can squirt extra electrons or suck some out. The wires and plates are electrically neutral which means there are equal numbers of electrons on both plates and wires.

Now we suddenly squirt some extra electrons into one of the plates and those extra electrons then flow into the plate and "face off" against the electrons sitting on the other plate, across the gap.

There are now more electrons on one plate than there are on the other and in response, some of the electrons on the other plate get repelled off of it and flow out through the wire attached to it, forming a brief burst of current that dies off when the potentials on both plates becomes equal and opposite.

Hence, for a brief instant, there was a squirt of current that entered one plate and left through the other even though there was no physical connection between the two plates. Since AC currents are all about sudden change, AC currents can flow through capacitors whereas DC currents cannot.